# thread 1 signal SIGABRT Apple Tutorial

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, multithreading

I am new to Objective-C and Xcode. I am trying to follow [this Apple tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/FirstTutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH3-SW1).

However, I have now finished it and keep getting Thread 1 Signal **SIGABRT**. It's not a long tutorial so I could easily do it again, but I would much rather learn from my mistakes than repeatedly start a project over and over.

I am using iOS 7 and Xcode 5.0.2.

The thread that it breaks on is 35 Main and the line says:

```
return UIApplicationMain (argc, argv, nil, NSStringFrom Class ([AppDelegate class]));
```

I've looked around the internet but I can't really find anything that is up to date with the latest version of Xcode.

Comment: See http://raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1 to learn how to debug this.

Comment: Minor nit-pick: It's Xcode, not xCode. Welcome.

Comment: Is the name of your app delegate "AppDelegate"? You didn't rename it to XYZAppDelegate or anything from the tutorial did you? Other question, why do you have 35 lines in your main.m? You should not add anything in there other than what was default generated for that tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies!
I followed everything the tutorial said. Does it need to be XYZAppDelegate? 
I found the document too rmaddy and followed it but the exception breakpoint didn't work and I'm not sure why.
I don't have 35 lines on main.m, I think it's the call stacks or something. If you look on the link rmaddy posted, he talks about call steps and stuff, 35 is the number next to main.m

Comment: @random I just realised I did actually need it to be XYZAppDelegate. Is there any way I can rename it? Or do I have to start the tutorial over again? I didn't think it would matter that much what the name is...

Comment: It doesn't have to be XYZAppDelegate, just everywhere in the tutorial he uses XYZAppDelegate, use AppDelegate.